# libcurl - I do not recieve mail GMAIL

Tags: gmail, libcurl

I'm sending an email from one to my other **gmail** account via the **c** libcurl library for **SMTP**. I've configured everything correctly I guess, because there aren't any errors. **The problem is I do not receive the email**.

I've already enabled the use of other applications for my **gmail** account.
I've also enabled verbose mode to see whats happening but nothing seems to be wrong.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```

On the end I get `Send some mail, I'll try my best` followed by some hash. After that there's a `Closing connection 0` message because I've set:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
```

Again, everything as expected.

Any idea why? Could it be because of content formating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't include the `CURLOPT_UPLOAD` thing and had a syntax error in the receiver.